# How to extract decimal point numbers and percentages from a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to extract percentages from thousands of comments, but the formats vary. A person may write ten percent as 10 or 10% or 10.00% or 10.0, so I need to be able to handle any of these possibilities. I am having two problems, the first is that my code doesn't capture the % when it is available and the second is that sometimes the regex statement captures a certain number several times.

```
FA_comment = "WPSGX 7.69% SVAIX 7.69% IWP 3.85% FLMVX 3.85% QUAYX 3.85% DEVLX 3.85% TINGX 19.23% TGVIX 23.08% ASYLX 15.38% CEMVX 11.54%"
tickers = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b', FA_comment)
numbers = re.findall(r'((\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})*))[%]?', FA_comment)
print(FA_comment)
print(tickers)
print(numbers
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
WPSGX 7.69% SVAIX 7.69% IWP 3.85% FLMVX 3.85% QUAYX 3.85% DEVLX 3.85% TINGX 19.23% TGVIX 23.08% ASYLX 15.38% CEMVX 11.54%
[u'WPSGX', u'SVAIX', u'IWP', u'FLMVX', u'QUAYX', u'DEVLX', u'TINGX', u'TGVIX', u'ASYLX', u'CEMVX']
[(u'7.69', u'7.69', u'.69'), (u'7.69', u'7.69', u'.69'), (u'3.85', u'3.85', u'.85'), (u'3.85', u'3.85', u'.85'), (u'3.85', u'3.85', u'.85'), (u'3.85', u'3.85', u'.85'), (u'19.23', u'19.23', u'.23'), (u'23.08', u'23.08', u'.08'), (u'15.38', u'15.38', u'.38'), (u'11.54', u'11.54', u'.54')]
```

Here is the output I would like to get:

```
[u'WPSGX', u'SVAIX', u'IWP', u'FLMVX', u'QUAYX', u'DEVLX', u'TINGX', u'TGVIX', u'ASYLX', u'CEMVX']
[u'7.69%', u'7.69%', u'3.85%', u'3.85%', u'3.85%', u'3.85%', u'19.23%', u'23.08', u'15.38%', u'11.54%']
```

Comment: The repeating values are because you use multiple search groups. Use non-capturing groups `(:?...)` to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` with two capture groups, one for the label and the other for the percentage.  Then, use a list comprehension to generate the 1D lists you expect for labels/percentages.

```
FA_comment = "WPSGX 7.69% SVAIX 7.69% IWP 3.85% FLMVX 3.85% QUAYX 3.85% DEVLX 3.85% TINGX 19.23% TGVIX 23.08% ASYLX 15.38% CEMVX 11.54%"
pcts = re.findall(r'\b([A-Z]+) (\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?(?!\S))', FA_comment)
print([i[0] for i in pcts])
print([i[1] for i in pcts])
```

This prints:

```
['WPSGX', 'SVAIX', 'IWP', 'FLMVX', 'QUAYX', 'DEVLX', 'TINGX', 'TGVIX',
 'ASYLX', 'CEMVX']
['7.69%', '7.69%', '3.85%', '3.85%', '3.85%', '3.85%', '19.23%', '23.08%',
 '15.38%', '11.54%']
```

Comment: Probably negative lookahead isn't needed. `re.findall(r'\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})*%?', FA_comment)` will also give same output.